# POST Parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, parameters, http-post

**How to post or send the params of CanDTO 3 times using for loop in the given post method:**

> parameter(params)
>   looping

```
    {   “CanDTO": [
        {
          "id": "",
          “canId": "3",
          "unitId": "3"   }, 
   {
          "id": "",
          “canId": "3",
          "unitId": "3"   },
        {
          "id": "",
          “canId": "4",
           "unitId": "3" 
   }  ],

      "id": "",   "Date": "01/01/2019",   "notes": "" }
```

> please anyone know about this.... Solve the issue

**Using this post method**

> how to send the params as loop, if selecting 3 options like above example...

```
func postmethod()
       {        
    let params = TotalcanDTO.init(CanDTO: CanDTO.init(id: “”,canId: 3,unitId: 3,),
    id:””,
    Date: 01/01/2019,
    notes: "")
            guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(params) else {
                return
            }


            let url = URL(string: "\(ApiManager.url)canApp/saveCanDetailsApp")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print ("error: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                        print ("server error")
                        return
                }

                if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
                    mimeType == "application/json",
                    let data = data,
                    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print ("got data: \(dataString)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        }
```

Comment: Why are you going to hit API 3 times to send the data? You can do it in once.

Comment: Please let me know which library are you using to call API i.e. Alamofire, AFNetworking or URLSession?

Comment: call API Using HTTP header, i select 3 items so the three items data are those so you know how to send a same parameter in loop , if we selecting 3 or 4or any value ie if i=x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do parameter as array.
var params=[Candto] ()

Then loop whenever you want and append your object to array.

Comment: please do an example with above params